# How to get submitted variable into a function

Tags: php, ajax

I am very sorry if this is very obvious, but I am banging my head against the wall on how to solve this

I have a form and I would like to use the submitted form value in to a function

the form:
**form.php**

```
<form action="my.php" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="my-item-calc" name="my-item-calc" value="29.00">
    <td>
        <input  type="submit">
</form>
```

**my.php**

```
class Jcart{
    private $calcdel =0;

    public function get_contents() {
        return $items;
        return $calc['calcdel'];
    }

    private function add_calc($calcdel){
        $validCalcdel = false;

        //Verify if the calculate value is numberic
        if (is_numeric($calcdel)) {
            $validCalcdel = true;
        }
        if ($validCaldel !== false) {
            $this->calcdel = $calcdel;
        }
    } 

    public function display_cart() {
        $config = $this->config; 
        $errorMessage = null;

        // Simplify some config variables
        $checkout = $config['checkoutPath'];
        $priceFormat = $config['priceFormat'];

        $calcdel = $config['calc']['calcdel'];

        // Use config values as literal indices for incoming POST values
        // Values are the HTML name attributes set in config.json
        $calcdel= $_POST[$calcdel];

        if ( isset($_POST[$calcdel]) ) {
            $calcdel = $_POST[$calcdel];
            $calcAdded = $this->add_calc($calcdel);
            if ($calcAdded = true){
                $this->calcdel = $calcdel;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I submit the form it will echo 29.00 for the $calcdel how ever this $this->calcdel output is empty

Any help how I would be able to pass the value into $this->calcdel and echo it out

Comment: You're using variable names susceptible to error - e.g. you're testing for `$validCalcdel` using `$validCalcdel` and in the next line `$validCaldel` - try to use short distinctive names. Also why do you have two return statements in method `get_contents()`? On top of that, both `$items` and `$calc['calcdel']` are unknown / undefined to the method.

Comment: @jibsteroos that works I am trying to get the submitted value into a function $this->calc = 29.00 when the form is submitted

Comment: update [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ftzr-37mk) - base example with class / method - you should be able to work it out from there. Tip, turn on error reporting and use a code editor with syntax highlighting!

Comment: @jibsteroos That all works fine, however I still need to get it into a function and that is where I'm struggling, thanks again for looking

Comment: in the example(fiddle) the `POST`-ed value _is_ processed by function `someFunction()`, what do you mean _"still need to get it into a function"_?

Comment: I need to get $this->calcdel become the the 29.00 I have submitted so far it is just empty

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```
class Jcart{
        private $calcdel =0;

    public function get_contents() {
            return $items;
            return $calc['calcdel'];
        }

    private function add_calc($calcdel){

                    $validCalcdel = false;
                    //Verify if the calculate value is numberic

                    if (is_numeric($calcdel)){
                        $validCalcdel = true;}
                    if ($validCaldel !== false){

                        $this->calcdel = $calcdel;
                    }

               } 

   public function display_cart() {

        $config = $this->config; 
        $errorMessage = null;

        // Simplify some config variables
        $checkout = $config['checkoutPath'];
        $priceFormat = $config['priceFormat'];

            $calcdel = $config['calc']['calcdel'];


        // Use config values as literal indices for incoming POST values
        // Values are the HTML name attributes set in config.json

           $calcdel= $_POST[$calcdel];

           $calcAdded = $this->add_calc($calcdel);
            if ($calcAdded){
               $this->calcdel = $calcdel;
            }
}}


$jcart = new Jcart();

   if (isset($_POST[$calcdel]))
   {
         $jcart->display_cart();
   }
```

Comment: It's always helpful to show us what exactly you think is the problem with the original code and what changes you've made to achieve the OP's desired outcome.

Comment: I am sorry that didn't put the value into the $this->calcdel

Comment: Now it doesn't echo out the $calcdel and the $this->calcdel is still empty sorry to be a pain

Comment: where did you added echo in your script? could you show that lines?

Comment: @carte the echo are put inside the function display_cart(){ echo '4'.$calcdel.'<br>';  echo '5'.$this->calcdel.'<br>';}

Comment: Sorry your code is not enough to understand what you are facing. ```$config['calc']['calcdel']``` let us know what value you are getting in this line?

Comment: @carte What would you need? All I am struggling with is to get the my-item-calc that I submit in the form into a function. I have no idea where to start with this as I thought you could catch the value with the $calcdel = $_POST['my-calc-del'] however it does not want to go into a function like $this->calcdel. I am sorry to pester you

Comment: In this line you have mispelt ```if ($validCaldel !== false)```